# Windows 10 background processes can not be stopped

Tags: windows-10, firefox

Today I realized that I could not open firefox after I had closed it a few minutes before.

I deleted firefox and installed it again and still had the same issue.

Eventually I realized that when I close firefox that it doesn't show up on the screen but there would still be a background-process that shows up. If I would try to open firefox again it would tell me that firefox is still running and can therefore not be opened again.

Then I realized that it happens with other programs as well. Here are the steps I have tried to try to solve this issue:

1. I restarted the pc several times
2. I tried to restore the system to a backup from yesterday
3. I tried to close the background-process through taskkill
4. I tried closing the processes through the task-manager
5. I disabled the kaspersky anti-virus
6. I disabled Malwarebytes

None of this things worked. I then created a new user-account and with the new account I do not have this problem.

If I try the command: `taskkill /im firefox.exe /F` it tells me, that the process could not be closed because there is no instance of this task currently being executed.

Does anybody have a suggestion on what else I could try?

Comment: Something has definitely happened with that User Account. The _Mozilla_ _Firefox_ Web-Browser has definitely not been uninstalled correctly. Maybe a Software Optimizer could help. They are sometimes able to remove the leftovers that still remain after an unsuccessful Uninstallation Procedure. Maybe the [Norton Utilities Premium](https://us.norton.com/norton-utilities) Desktop Software Suite could help. But do not keep your fingers crossed. These days, most people tend to recommend just Clean Reinstallation Procedures.

Answer (score 0):

*I then created a new user-account and with the new account I do not have this problem.*

There is an account profile error which is preventing Firefox from closing properly. Firefox will normally close properly in a good user profile.

So at this point, you need to back up the documents in your existing profile to a neutral location (like a USB Key).  Then create a new account and delete the old account. Recover documents from the USB key.

If you wish to use the same User Name for the new Windows Profile, be very, very certain you have all your documents, favourites you want, email (PST and maybe OST files) and so on. Make sure you have a separate Administrator account. Delete the profile , restart and build a new profile with the same account user name